# Pressing specific 3 buttons at a time not working but other 3 combinations are working

Tags: keyboard

I'm playing Pro Evolution Soccer 2018 with Logitech K200 (with default keyboard settings) on Windows 8.1 Pro, and to sprint in north-west direction I'm pressing left_arrow + top_arrow + E and it is not working also to shoot in south-west direction left_arrow + down_arrow + A are not working together, but I'm able to sprint in north-east, south-east and south-west using the arrows keys and the E key.

So, some 3 key combinations are working some aren't working.

Please help me fix this so that I can play well :)

Comment: @TrentHawkins so the limit is not only based on how many combinations we can press at a time but also on what specific combinations can be pressed ?

Comment: Yes, it's a hardware limitation present in most keyboards to some degree. The combinations that result in your 'E' key's signal being blocked are a bit odd - as it is clearly neither the up_arrow nor left_arrow blocking 'E', as **north**-east and south-**west** work with 'E'. Perhaps when two arrow keys are pressed at once it sends a single signal for the diagonal rather than two separate button presses, and the up/left diagonal signal blocks the 'E'? ***shrug*** it's hard to tell, best you can do is try to rebind the controls in game so regular play does not trigger these key rollover issues.

Comment: @TrentHawkins thanks for the info, I'll rebind the controls in the game